# Can I test multiplayer from Ipad and Simulator

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, multiplayer

I have to test game running in multiplayer from the iPad simulator and iPad. Can i test it? For this time when I am running program simultaneously on both and trying to send invite player it is being failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't test multiplayer and send invite from iPad to Simulator, or vice-versa, you need two devices. Try getting a friend that has an iPad to test with you.

All the best.